# Mule API Console returns status 0, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, mule

I am developing an API using mule, this api uses the api console to test the application using a raml. My API works perfect in Internet Explorer and Postman, but that is not the case in Chrome or Mozilla. This is the error that I get from the Mozilla console

```html
          "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
minErr/<@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:49455:12
beginPhase@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:64316:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:64060:11
apply@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console.js:1044:11
handleResponse@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console.js:1096:11
RAML.Directives.sidebar/<.controller</$scope.tryIt/</<@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console.js:1426:37
.Deferred/promise.then/</</<@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:32199:30
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:32042:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.add@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:32088:7
.Deferred/promise.then/</<@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:32198:8
.each@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:29317:14
.Deferred/promise.then/<@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:32195:7
.Deferred@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:32255:4
.Deferred/promise.then@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:32194:13
RAML.Directives.sidebar/<.controller</$scope.tryIt/<@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console.js:1424:17
Anonymous.prototype.authenticate/<.then@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console.js:2194:33
RAML.Directives.sidebar/<.controller</$scope.tryIt@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console.js:1421:15
$parseFunctionCall@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:61866:15
ngEventHandler/</callback@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:71092:17
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:63962:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:64061:18
ngEventHandler/<@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:71097:17
jQuery.event.dispatch@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:33377:15
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@https://127.0.0.1:8444/api/loanmgmt/1.0/console/scripts/api-console-vendor.js:33064:6
"
```

This is the line in api.console.js where the error is generated but I cannot figure out why.

```js
                jQuery.ajax(request.toOptions()).then(
                  function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) { handleResponse(jqXhr); },
                  function(jqXhr) { handleResponse(jqXhr); }
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an Mule application and i am not a javascript developer, it was hard for me to attack the problem through Javascript and the Browser console, in fact, there is no much info about the problem. This was crearly a RAML problem becsause it was not sending the request and the debugger never stopped, so, I did some digging in the raml removing parts of it, there was a parameter that was causing the problem because it didn't correspond with the api design, if I had investigated this approach earlier, I would've resolved this sooner.